# MultipartFile to .zip

Tags: java, spring

How to convert a MultipartFile to .zip and then to byte?
Something like:

```
 MultipartFile file;
 ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(file.getInputStream());
 Base64.getEncoder().encode(zip)
```

Comment: For what purpose? are you receiving the file and storing it that way, or reading a file from disk and providing it as a response.

Comment: I want to store in my database as a byte. Correct the question

Comment: you may want to take a look at this[File system or db storage of files](https://habiletechnologies.com/blog/better-saving-files-database-file-system/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting `MultipartFile` to `.zip` file and retrieving its bytes:

```
public ResponseEntity handleFile(@RequestParam MultipartFile file) throws IOException 
{
    InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream();
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
    ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(file.getOriginalFilename());
    zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(zipEntry);

    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while((length = inputStream.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
        zipOutputStream.write(bytes, 0, length);
    }
    zipOutputStream.close();

    // Do something with the byteArrayOutputStream
    System.out.println(byteArrayOutputStream.toString());

    return ResponseEntity.accepted().build();
}
```